# SQL find consecutive days of specific threshold reached

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns; the_day and amount_raised. I want to find the count of consecutive days that at least 1 million dollars was raised. Am I able to do this in SQL? Ideally, I'd like to create a column that counts the consecutive days and then starts over if the 1 million dollar threshold is not reached.

What I've done thus far is create a third column that puts a 1 in the row if 1 million was reached. Could I create a subquery and count the consecutive 1's listed, then reset when it hits 0? [image]

and here is the desired output

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do it in SQL. Do you want to get a running total and then check if it has reached 1 million or not?

Comment: not a running total, just specific to the day. for example, 1/11 -- 1/14 would count as 4, but then it would stop counting because 1/15 did not break the 1 million threshold. does that make sense?

Comment: Okay I get you... so once you assign 1's and 0' s to all the rows in the table what needs to be done?

Comment: that was my initial thought; using that third column to say 1 means it was over a million and 0 means less. so maybe I should change the third column to say CASE WHEN amount_raised >= '1000000' then 1 ELSE 0. But I'm not sure where to go from there. any ideas?

Comment: What is your desird output...?

Comment: I updated my question with a new picture. I want to count the consecutive 1s in the third column, and then reset after there is a 0. this way, I can see the count of consecutive days that the threshold was reached. I am going to be doing this over a three year period, so I want it to be easy to see the long streaks of 1 million reached. does that make sense?

Comment: I added the desired output. thank you

Comment: Try the soln I posted... this should work for your requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dt,amt,
case when amt>=1000000 then -1+row_number() over(partition by col order by dt) 
else 0 end col1
from (select *, sum(case when amt >= 1000000 then 0 else 1 end) over(order by dt) col 
      from t) x
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/FKNVR3312)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT the_day,
       amount_raised,
       million_threshold,
       CASE WHEN million_threshold <> lag_million_threshold AND million_threshold = lead_million_threshold
            THEN 1
            WHEN million_threshold = lag_million_threshold
            THEN SUM(million_threshold) OVER ( ORDER BY the_day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )
            ELSE 0
        END AS consecutive_day_cnt          
  FROM
     (
       SELECT  the_day, 
               amount_raised,
               million_threshold,
               LAG(million_threshold,1) OVER ( ORDER BY the_day ) AS lag_million_threshold,
               LEAD(million_threshold,1) OVER ( ORDER BY the_day ) AS lead_million_threshold
         FROM
            ( 
              SELECT  the_day,
                      amount_raised,
                      CASE WHEN amount_raised >= 1000000
                           THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                       END AS million_threshold
                 FROM Yourtable
            )
      );
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I am getting the following error: ERROR: function sum() does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Which db are you using?

Comment: I'm using my company's database. is that what you're asking? sorry, im not really well versed in db language.

Comment: Is it Oracle or SQL Server or any other database?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: Its working for me on my db.... Did you try running the individual queries.. like the inner most first then the first outermost and the final outermost query..

Comment: It ran successfully using your updated solution, but the consecutive day count is incorrect. It lists 0 successfully until 1/10, and then 1,2,3,4 for 1/11 -- 1/14 just like it is suppose to. But then it lists 1,4,0,0,0,0,0,1,7,7,1,9,10,11,12,13,14

Comment: what is the best way to send you an image of the output I got from your updated solution? doesn't appear I can post images in the comments section

Comment: I understood the issue which u commented just now... Let me try it and get back to u..

Comment: sounds good. I can post a screenshot in my original question if you'd like. I posted my output below your answer but it is only viewable to me until it is peer reviewed.

Comment: the answer below works. Happy to keep trying your answer if you'd like too test out more answers